# Can I change the value of a variable?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to JasperReports, but I kind of feel like I'm getting it. After all it is just another mark-up language.

My scenario is that I have a table of data, with the date and some other text columns, and I want to to display a subtotal for each section of the data based on a date. I am expecting zero, one, or many dates to be in the table.

I have a variable defined that calculates the sum of the rows, but I want to reset the sum to zero with each sub-group, is it possible?

Here is my Variable declaration:

```
<variable name="G_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
<variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{ROW_NUMBER}.intValue() != 9)?$F{ITEM_COUNT}:new Integer(0))]]></variableExpression>
<initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
```

Is there a way I can use this variable, resetting to 0 when a new date is found, or am I using the wrong type to do what I want?

As a caveat, I am editing the .jrxml file in a text editor, not iReport.

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to figure out from reading the dtd is that groups are available to trigger a reset event.

```
<variable name="G_COUNT" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum" resetType="Group" resetGroup="SubCalc">
<variableExpression><![CDATA[(($F{ROW_ORDINAL}.intValue() != 9)?$F{ITEM_COUNT}:new Integer(0))]]></variableExpression>
<initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]></initialValueExpression>

<group name="SubCalc">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROW_ORDINAL} == 1]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

So when the ROW_ORDINAL == 1 it triggers a reset event, which sets the value of G_COUNT to the initialValueExpression